# What Event Handler is called when C# ComboBox value is changed by Typing

Tags: c#, combobox, event-handling, edit

I would like to capture the event when user changes value of ComboBox by typing.

The `SelectedIndexChanged` only works if user chooses an option from drop down value, what about when ComboBox text is changed by typing.

Comment: Forms or WPF? (or other)

Comment: [textchanged event?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Forms

Comment: From what I know it's the same event, it just needs to be triggered by pressing enter twice or by blurring.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz then go after textchanged event. check the link I've posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TextChanged event will work for you

```
ComboBox1_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```